# Git replace files in local branch with peer branch

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I had an issue to resolve for which I made a branch "my-branch".  This was branched from "develop".  I suddenly had to stop work on this issue to focus on a more pressing task.  During my absence on this issue, a team member named Joe had taken up this work.  Joe created another branch from "develop" named "joe-branch".  He then manually copied files from my branch, made a series of changes, and made a series of commits to "joe-branch".  I now would like to incorporate these changes to my branch.  I would like to continue work on my branch without disturbing "joe-branch" or "develop".

Questions:

1. If I open GitBash to the top level of my branch, can I use `git merge joe-branch` to copy all of his changes to my branch?  Is there a better command-line approach?
2. Is the way we have organized our branches okay?  Would there have been a better way to coordinate our work?

Comment: The beauty of Git is that branches are practically free; they cost a few bytes. Go create one off of your branch and go experiment with #1. Only Git can tell, we can but guess. As for #2, of course there's a better way than manually copying files from one branch to the next, see #1: they should just have branched off of your branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override only one file

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/master <filepath>
```

If you want to take all changed files

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: If "joe-branch" hasn't pulled changes into "develop", would using origin/master still work?